# How do I use the laplace transformations to solve this initial value problem?

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, transformation, fourier-transform, initial-value-problems

So I have been given $\ddot{x} + 8\dot{x} +16x = e^t$ and $x(0) = 0, \dot{x} = 0$. How would I go about solving this initial value problem? As I am unsure of where to begin or what to do. Anything that would help me I would really appreciate!

Comment: Do you have examples of using Laplace transforms to solve initial value problems? If not, see this page for instance: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx.

Comment: It's a three-step process: 1. Take the LT of the entire equation. 2. Solve the resulting algebraic equation for $X(s).$ 3. Take the inverse LT of $X(s)$ to obtain $x(t).$